# NodeJS app deployed on heroku issue - not retrieving data from database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I'm having an issue with my full-stack application, (MySQL-Express-React-NodeJS). I have deployed it to Heroku everything is working except the pages that are connected to get or post to ClearDB MySQL database! Any advises or hints on something that I might have forgot to do? I'm also using the ClearDB add-on from Heroku if that helps.

`server.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);

const connection = require("./app/Models/database");
// require user the route
const user = require("./app/routes/user");
// require the doctor route
const doctor = require("./app/routes/doctor");

// require the question route
const questions = require("./app/routes/questions.js");

// require the schedule route
const schedule = require("./app/routes/schedule");
const appointement = require("./app/routes/appointment");
const socket = require("socket.io");
const io = socket(server);

app.use(cors());
// set the port
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// define the user router
app.use("/users", user);
app.use("/doctor", doctor);
app.use("/questions", questions);

app.use("/schedule", schedule);
app.use("/appointment", appointement);
app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
  if (error instanceof SyntaxError) {
    //Handle SyntaxError here.
    return res.status(500).send({ data: "Invalid data" });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

const peers = {};

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  //
  if (!peers[socket.id]) {
    peers[socket.id] = socket.id;
  }

  socket.emit("yourID", socket.id); //  allows you to emit custom events on the server and client

  io.sockets.emit("allUsers", peers); //will send to all the clients ......socket.broadcast.emit will send the message to all the other clients except the newly created connection

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    delete peers[socket.id]; //after the user leave the room
  });

  socket.on("callUser", (data) => {
    io.to(data.userToCall).emit("hello", {
      signal: data.signalData,
      from: data.from,
    }); //io.to('some room').emit('some event');
  });

  socket.on("acceptCall", (data) => {
    io.to(data.to).emit("callAccepted", data.signal);
  });
});

//test route

app.get("/test", function (req, res) {
  res.send( "test");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is Running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Heroku logs:

```
2021-01-04T18:46:17.729977+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-01-04T18:46:17.732430+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-01-04T18:46:18.729190+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-01-04T18:46:18.801647+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-01-04T18:46:53.555253+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-01-04T18:46:57.234794+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-01-04T18:46:57.234819+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 start
2021-01-04T18:46:57.234819+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2021-01-04T18:46:57.234820+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-04T18:46:58.471423+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/server.js:61
2021-01-04T18:46:58.471444+00:00 app[web.1]: console.log(`Server is Running in port:${port}`);
2021-01-04T18:46:58.471446+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-01-04T18:46:58.471446+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-04T18:46:58.471447+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: port is not defined
2021-01-04T18:46:58.471447+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:61:44)
2021-01-04T18:46:58.471447+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:482:28)
2021-01-04T18:46:58.471448+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.emit (node:events:388:22)
2021-01-04T18:46:58.471448+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitListeningNT (node:net:1329:10)
2021-01-04T18:46:58.471449+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:79:21)
2021-01-04T18:46:58.502509+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code 1
2021-01-04T18:46:58.503140+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! path /app
2021-01-04T18:46:58.509321+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command failed
2021-01-04T18:46:58.509747+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command sh -c node server.js
2021-01-04T18:46:58.536286+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-04T18:46:58.542292+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-01-04T18:46:58.542507+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-01-04T18_46_58_510Z-debug.log
2021-01-04T18:46:58.614100+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-01-04T18:46:58.673495+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-01-04T18:46:58.677305+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-01-04T18:47:24.050526+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-01-04T18:47:27.323089+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-04T18:47:27.323103+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 start
2021-01-04T18:47:27.323103+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2021-01-04T18:47:27.323104+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-04T18:47:27.950882+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/server.js:61
2021-01-04T18:47:27.950900+00:00 app[web.1]: console.log(`Server is Running in port:${port}`);
2021-01-04T18:47:27.950901+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-01-04T18:47:27.950903+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-04T18:47:27.950903+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: port is not defined
2021-01-04T18:47:27.950903+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:61:44)
2021-01-04T18:47:27.950904+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:482:28)
2021-01-04T18:47:27.950904+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.emit (node:events:388:22)
2021-01-04T18:47:27.950904+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitListeningNT (node:net:1329:10)
2021-01-04T18:47:27.950905+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:79:21)
2021-01-04T18:47:27.970852+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code 1
2021-01-04T18:47:27.971425+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! path /app
2021-01-04T18:47:27.976210+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command failed
2021-01-04T18:47:27.976596+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command sh -c node server.js
2021-01-04T18:47:27.987341+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-04T18:47:27.987620+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-01-04T18:47:27.987792+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-01-04T18_47_27_977Z-debug.log
2021-01-04T18:47:28.067423+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-01-04T18:47:28.111585+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-01-04T18:48:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ishaqatfarah@gmail.com
2021-01-04T18:50:08.503349+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=speakout-2.herokuapp.com request_id=41eadebc-6547-4735-975c-47f07af41139 fwd="46.185.242.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https     
2021-01-04T18:50:13.899678+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=speakout-2.herokuapp.com request_id=f9c641f9-30c1-4ef7-a184-0d286cecf4c0 fwd="46.185.242.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-04T18:50:37.722683+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=speakout-2.herokuapp.com request_id=a897151b-2c68-440d-bb39-877ad0e80b3c fwd="46.185.242.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https     
2021-01-04T18:50:38.328012+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=speakout-2.herokuapp.com request_id=3b546e46-3812-4a18-8f78-f585c9f3e740 fwd="46.185.242.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-04T18:50:44.226260+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=speakout-2.herokuapp.com request_id=df1690f0-5e59-4105-aae7-857d2a2ef8ff fwd="46.185.242.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https     
2021-01-04T18:50:44.682096+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=speakout-2.herokuapp.com request_id=d4bee131-4929-4f80-96dd-d829a6c53bde fwd="46.185.242.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: "expect [sic] the pages that are connected to get or post to clearDB Mysql database"—what's the _specific_ problem? I don't see any relevant error messages in the logs. Please read [ask].

Comment: I see you edited your question to fix a typo but didn't bother to respond to my comment. If you don't explain the specific problem clearly we won't be able to help.

Comment: Yeah well sorry i’m honestly lost,  and the deadline is getting closer! cannot really tell whats the problem.. i guess i will start over again.. and thanks alot for the attention 

Comment: I will get back to you sure after giving it another shot!

Comment: If you aren't receiving any errors, are you sure there's data _in_ your database?

Comment: yes in sure, im using workbench and when i write a query i can display the data

Comment: And you're connecting to the same ClearDB database in both cases? If there's data in the database you're definitely going to have to provide more info. Any error messages would be helpful. If none exist, add some logging statements to your code.

Comment: @Chris can u take a look at the new logs ??

Comment: my clearDB is added on a separate application .. i have 2 heroku apps .. one has the DB and another one where i pushed my code .. i used heroku config:set CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL='mysql://b0633d23088e42..etc' to connect it but not sure if its correct :(

Comment: Thanks for updating, Joy! Are these complete? They look mangled, e.g. `ode`, `unning`...

Comment: i just updated them

Comment: now im having the app running but as i told u previously .. for example i have a page that was supposed to fetch data from the database and render it there... its giving me error fetching the data :'(

Comment: i also cannot log in with the users i already used to log in with while i was on the localhost

Comment: so i guess its database connection right ?

Comment: "its giving me error fetching the data"—again, I'm not seeing an error in the logs here. There were _some_ errors in the previous mangled revision containing `ode` and `unning`, but I wasn't able to fully read them. Can you show the full error messages, please?

Comment: "i also cannot log in with the users i already used to log in with while i was on the localhost… so i guess its database connection right ?"—no (at least it shouldn't be). Your development database and your production database should be completely separate. User accounts should not work across environments. It's _expected_ that users and data are different in both environments. Again, are you entirely sure that there is data in your _hosted_ database? (If your development machine is connected to the same database as your production instance please let us know. That's an antipattern.)

Comment: yes i have been working on the same DB for development, so do u suggest that i create a new one for the production ?

Comment: Yes, but in that case you have another issue and creating a second database right now may just muddy the waters. Are you able to share the error messages you're getting?

Comment: i couldn't post in a comment i edited my post up there, can u check it ?

Comment: its working now!!! thank you anyways